# Problema al cargar scripts en una parcial cshtml

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, cshtml, .netframework

estoy teniendo problemas al cargar los scripts de mi vista parcial , estos se suponen que se cargan al momento de copiar la pagina , pero no se cargan . Para probar simplemente hice un console.log pero igual no manda el mensaje , lo cual me indica que no se copian o cargan al momento de copiar el html , la vista es esta :

```
    @model CapaModelo.ClienteyContratoConID_VM
﻿


    @* Estilo del error *@
    <style>
        form .error {
            color: red;
        }
    
        input.error {
            border-color: red;
        }
    </style>

<div id="<DivModificarCliente</Div>" class="container shadow-lg p-4">
    <form class="row" id="ModificarClienteyContratoForm">

        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="IdCliente" id="IdCliente" value="@Model.IdCliente" />
        </div>

        <p class="text-start my-3 fw-bold fs-4">Datos Cliente</p>

        <!-- Lado izquierdo -->

        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="NombreCliente" class="form-label">Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NombreClienteMod" name="NombreClienteMod" value="@Model.NomCliente">
            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Apellido" class="form-label">Apellido:</label>
                <input type="text" name="ApellidoMod" id="ApellidoMod" class="form-control" value="@Model.Apellido">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="Cedula" class="form-label">Cedula:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CedulaMod" name="CedulaMod" remote="@Url.Action("ValidarCedula", "Cliente")" value="@Model.Cedula">
            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="TelefonoCliente" class="form-label">Celular:</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="TelefonoClienteMod" name="TelefonoClienteMod" value="@Model.TelCliente">
            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="Correo" class="form-label">Correo:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="CorreoMod" name="CorreoMod" value="@Model.correo">
            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </div>


        <div class=" p-4">
            <hr style="border: 2PX solid BLACK" />
        </div>


        <p class="text-start my-3 fw-bold fs-4">Datos de Contrato</p>


        <div class="col-6" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <label for="Deposito" class="form-label">Deposito Inical:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="DepositoMod" name="DepositoMod" value="@Model.Deposito">
            <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="">
                <label for="IdCuarto" class="form-label">Cuarto: </label>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <select class="selectpicker form-control" select data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith" id="IdCuarto" name="IdCuarto" aria-label="Seleccionar">
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="IdCuarto">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @*value="@Model.IdCuarto"*@


        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="FechaInicio" class="form-label">Fecha de Inicio de Contrato</label>
            <input type="date" name="FechaInicio" id="FechaInicio" value="@Model.FechaIni.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" class="w-100 form-control" />
        </div>


        <div class="col-6 mb-3">
            <label for="FechaFinMod" class="form-label">Fecha de Fin de Contrato</label>
            <input type="date" name="FechaFinMod" id="FechaFinMod" class="w-100 form-control" value="@(Model.Fechafin.HasValue ? Model.Fechafin.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : string.Empty)" />
        </div>




        <div style="text-align: right; background-color: #D3CECE;" class="p-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="las la-save"></i> Agregar</button>
            <button id="cancelButtonMod" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="las la-undo"></i> Cancelar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


@section scripts {
    <div id="scriptsContainer">
        <!-- Configuración de la tabla de Cargos -->
        <script src="~/scripts/cliente/ValidacionesMod.js"></script>
        <script>
            console.log('scriptcarga');
        </script>
    </div>
}
```

y este es el JS :

```
    $('#TablaDeCliente').on('click', '.editar-btn', function () {
    var idCliente = $(this).data('idcliente');
    $.get("/Cliente/ObtenerClienteycontratoPorId", { IdCliente: idCliente }, function (html) {
        $('#DivTablaCliente').hide();
        $("#DivModificarClienteContrato").html(html);
        $('#DivModificarClienteContrato').show();

        // Reinicializar el selectpicker después de agregar el contenido
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    }).fail(function (error) {
        console.error("Error al obtener los datos del registro:", error);

        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Error al obtener los datos del registro',
            text: 'Ha ocurrido un error al intentar obtener los datos del registro. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo.',
            showConfirmButton: true
        });

    });
});
```

Y este es el controlador:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ObtenerClienteycontratoPorId(int   IdCliente)
    {
        var ClienteyContrato = cliente_LN.PoblarVistaModificar(IdCliente);
        if (ClienteyContrato == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return PartialView("Modificar", ClienteyContrato);
    }
```

Se supone que cuando le doy click al boton de editar , que esta en una tabla de Jquery data tables El hace una consulta a la base de datos con el ID que el consigue y puebla una vista con toda esa informacion , lo cual hace . Pero nunca carga bien los scripts de la vista parcial de Modificar , quisieera saber como solucionar este problema . Lo que he intentado simplemente es Cambiar el Controlador que en vez de retornar una vista parcial me retorne a la vista en si . En vez de copiar el contenido HTML y copiarlo en un div , pero lo que quiero es que carge los scripts tambien . No tengo idea porque no los carga a com oesta actualemente . Cualquier aclaracion es Agradecida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalmente se tiene un `Layout`, el cual en forma simple puede verse así:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

En `@RenderBody` se renderiza la vista, pero además puedes crear `section` e incluirlo en otra parte del Layout, esto funciona no solo para los scripts si que también para CSS y HTML, es decir una vista puede incluir partes de HTML no solo en el body si que también en otros lado (útil para incluir elementos en el menú del sitio según la vista)

Cuando una vista la llamas a renderizar como **vista parcial** NO pasa por el layout, entonces las secciones no son incluidas ¿Donde las va a incluir si no hay layout?. Piensa, además, que si volviera a cargar el layout se formaría un bucle infinito

Lo más simple es agregar las etiquetas `script` directamente, o sea cambiar esto:

```
@section scripts {
    <div id="scriptsContainer">
        <!-- Configuración de la tabla de Cargos -->
        <script src="~/scripts/cliente/ValidacionesMod.js"></script>
        <script>
            console.log('scriptcarga');
        </script>
    </div>
}
```

Por esto

```
<div id="scriptsContainer">
    <!-- Configuración de la tabla de Cargos -->
    <script src="~/scripts/cliente/ValidacionesMod.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log('scriptcarga');
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion sobre que no pasan por el Layout , eso si no me lo sabia , sin embargo , mis scripts siguen sin cargar , El problema radica que al momento que agarro los elementos html ignora la seccion de scripts , a como se mira abajo hay uno que es :      **<script>
        console.log('scriptcarga');
    </script>** pero ni eso aparece .

Comment: Yo he probado exactamente tu mismo código, y al sacar el `@section` me imprime el `console`. Como estas cargando la vista parcial???

Comment: En mi vista principal llamada Index hay una seccion : **<div id="DivModificarClienteContrato" style="display:none" class="container shadow-lg p-4">
    @*Aqui se muestra el html de la de copia*@
</div>** copio los elementos html de la vista modificar , el js se encarga de agarrar el html a como esta demostrado anteriormente y mediante la accion del controlador , le retorna los valores del @mode. etc...

Comment: Encontre la solucion , sucede de que al cargar la vista parcial , Como decias no carga la seccion de scrips . Solo era de agregar las etiquetas de scripts sin ningun div ni otra sintaxis adicional